# Configure a Tor proxy on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, tor

Here's my issue: I'm using the university internet connection quite often. The network has a firewall which blocks the connection of some programs like IRC (Xchat, Irssi), sometimes even the Software Updater and some other applications.

I've surfed on the web and found out that I can "overtake" the firewall using a Tor proxy. But the instructions on how configure it are confused and often incorrect.
Can you please help me in find out how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would recommend just using a VPN instead of a Tor proxy. Any particular reason why you don't want to use one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Install the official Tor proxy

Tor and its official SOCKS 5 proxy are pretty quick to get running on Ubuntu. Going off of [the Tor Project website's installation instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian), do the following:

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the following (replace `xenial` with the release you're running if you're not on 16.04 Xenial Xerus):

   ```
   sudo -i
   echo deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor.list
   echo deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor.list
   gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
   gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | apt-key add -
   apt update
   apt install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
   exit
   ```

Now the Tor SOCKS 5 proxy will be running on your machine, `127.0.0.1`, on port `9050`. Remember that this is a SOCKS 5 proxy, not an HTTP proxy.

Your Tor proxy will automatically start when your machine boots. You can run `sudo service tor restart` or other actions like `start`, `stop`, and `status` to control the Tor proxy on your machine.

### Apt through Tor

Going off of [the apt-transport-tor Github README](https://github.com/diocles/apt-transport-tor), to get `apt` to work through Tor:

1. Back up `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo -i
   apt update
   apt install apt-transport-tor
   sed -i 's/ http/ tor+http/g' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
   apt update
   exit
   ```
4. Make sure to fix any error messages that appear (if needed, restore the files you backed up)

**Note:** Be aware that some programs, like Google Chrome, will modify their `.list` file, so those programs may automatically switch back to trying to connect directly when checking for updates instead of going through Tor.

### In-program proxy settings

A lot of programs connect just fine through Tor if you edit the proxy settings to:

- **Host:** `127.0.0.1`
- **Port:** `9050`
- **Proxy type (if it asks):** `SOCKS5`
- **Username/Password (if it asks):** both set to the name of the program

### Proxy wrapper

Other programs, like `irssi`, need to use `torsocks`. There are two ways of doing this:

1. `torsocks` gives error messages:

   ```
   torsocks -i command arguments
   ```
2. `torsocks` is quiet (useful for programs like `irssi` that assume they fully control what's shown on the terminal):

   ```
   TORSOCKS_LOG_LEVEL=1 torsocks -i command arguments
   ```

Comment: Well, the firewall didn't allowed me to generate the key. Now I've manage to do it and I'll test it on Monday. Thanks for now anyway.

Oh, and if I go on Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy and I set Socks Host on 127.0.0.1:9050 all the traffic is going through there, right?

Comment: It should be going through Tor, assuming the program isn't badly written. You can gain more confidence by connecting to a `.onion` address suitable for the program (such as `https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion` for a browser).

Comment: So, the test was a failure. The firewall doesn't allow me to connect through Tor protocol, everything keeps loading (browsers, irssi, etc...), but never connects. As soon as I turn off the proxy the browser start to work again.
Any suggestion?

Comment: One thing to check is whether Tor is running when you try to connect using it. You can run `sudo netstat -plnt | fgrep :9050` and see if you get a line saying `tor` is running. If it is, but you can't get through, take a look at [Tor bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en), which use unpublished addresses. You may even need to use obfuscated bridges (also described in the previous link), which hides not only what you're doing through Tor from your ISP, it hides that you're using Tor in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, Tor is running but it still doesn't connect. I'm trying bridges, but it doesn't change anything. I'm using obfs4.

It gets stuck here.
`Oct 13 09:48:25.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: Pluggable transport proxies still configuring
Oct 13 09:48:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Oct 13 09:48:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server`

It doesn't say that it can't connect, it just freeze.

On TorProject website they says to avoid tor from the Ubuntu Universe. Do you think is somehow related?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't display the terminal strings in the right way:

`Oct 13 09:48:25.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: Pluggable transport proxies still configuring
Oct 13 09:48:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Oct 13 09:48:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
`

Comment: `Oct 13 09:48:25.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (cached): $468086FC307AA03874C5BF1AFC497784F987BFBD~Unnamed at 194.132.209.229

Oct 13 09:48:25.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: Pluggable transport proxies still configuring

Oct 13 09:48:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

Oct 13 09:48:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
`

Comment: Okay, there's no way to display it in a proper way. I'm sorry mate

Comment: Hi, do you know how to set a proxy in front of Tor proxy? My country ban tor, I need a proxy to connect tor network.

Comment: `gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89`
`gpg: WARNING: nothing exported`

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @EugeneGr.Philippov `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810`